# Time Series Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset that has been recorded periodical for quantities of items sold. this dataset contains the following columns: Item ID, Date(2015-01-01, 2022-12-01), Quantities of items sold. how do I split the  dataset by which item id's have less or equal to 12 data points historically as I am trying to forecast item sales for the next 6 months. In Python

grouped_data = df.groupby('item_id').apply(lambda x: x[x['date'].count() <= 12])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is what I have so far                                                                                                         #import libraries
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

#read in the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv') 

#split the dataset into train and test
X_train = df[df['Date'] < '2022-01-01']
X_test = df[df['Date'] >= '2022-12-01']

#replace missing values with 0
X_train = X_train.fillna(0)
X_test = X_test.fillna(0)

#print the shape of the train and test datasets
print('Train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('Test shape:', X_test.shape)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to this by just applying this code: Good_data = p[p['Create month/year']>48].index.values
Good_data.shape.
This filters our Data to get only the item indexes that has datapoints greater than 4 years, and looking at the shape of the list.